# JSP cant find the servlet reference (404)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

So as I'm trying to run this code example **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNRSNDm08wk** I did my servlet class and also the form is poiting at it. However when I clic submit it doesn't seem to recognize regServlet as the identifier for my servlet since it's giving me the error 404. It looks for a file inside the jsp page directory. Is there anywhere I can check for those references?

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RegServlet")
public class RegServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    StringBuilder csvSkills =   new  StringBuilder();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String hdnParam =   request.getParameter("pagename");
            if(hdnParam.equals("register")){
....
```

The html form:

```
<form action="RegServlet" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="pagename" value="login"/>
        <p>Nombre de Usuario</p>
        <input type="text" name="regUserName" required value="usuario" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='usuario'" onFocus="if(this.value=='usuario')this.value='' "><br>
       <p>Contraseña</p>
        <input type="password" name="regUserPass"  required value="Contraseña" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Contraseña'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Contraseña')this.value='' "> 
        <br><input type="submit" value="Crear Cuenta">

      </form>
```

Comment: change the action to `action="/RegServlet"` and try

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /RegServlet
type Status report
message /RegServlet
description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: what IDE you are using?

Comment: Can you verify that you have the file `RegServlet.class` inside the bean/ directory in your WAR?

Comment: Eclipse Luna IDE (i'm just typing more words here)

Comment: ok i found something. Checking the war file i found the the servletsclass was inside bean folder and also that there was a servlet reference "RegServlet1" in web.xml so i thought that i could change my both codes to RegServlet and it will be ok. however i got this error :
**The servlets named [RegServlet1] and [bean.RegServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/RegServlet1] which is not permitted
 at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)**

where can i map my servlets??

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to add the context inside the action path dynamically in your JSP as:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sampleServlet">
```

Comment: this actually worked! Thanks! it didnt insert the info on my table but it didn't threw any error! so i should have another mistake somewhere

Comment: @AleRojas You 're welcome. Let us know if you are facing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

As your code currently stands, your servlet should be accessible from the following path:

```
http://localhost:8080/{app-name}/RegServlet
```

where `{app-name}` is the name of the WAR file.  If you cannot access this directly from a web browser, then likely the WAR does not exist, or the `RegServlet.class` file is not present inside the WAR.

When you try to access the servlet from your form, you need to make certain that it is using the above path or else it won't be accessible.  You can check this from the JavaScript console.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fIEr03M.png ok this is the structure I have. This is driving me crazy I'm sorry.